# Editable block in footer typo3 neos

Tags: php, typo3, neoscms

I need to add editable from backend custom block to footer in Typo3 neos.
How can I do it? The place where I want to add a block is marked in red:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is an example of how to do it:
http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/IntegratorsCookbook/EditableSharedFooter.html